# Alternatives to Back Navigation Prevention on Mobile Browsers

Tags: mobile, browser

I need some advice on how to work around a problem that I am currently facing. I develop a single page web application where the user walks through a specified process flow. A legal requirement is that the user may not interrupt the process and if they do, they need to start over from the beginning. That means there should be no way to go back to a previous step (our web application already aborts the process in such a case) but sometimes users accidentally navigate back via system buttons or swipes. This leads to frustration on both ends.

On desktop browsers this poses no problem because the known methods of "disabling" the back button work very well and also accidental back navigation happens way less. However, for mobile devices there are additional (justified) safe-guards to prevent such behavior. Still in our use case it is preferred, even by the end users from what we were able to obtain through feedback.

My question is: What could be a viable approach to improve the User Experience in such a scenario without trying to "disable" the back navigation?